# SQL OneToMany Relationship

Tags: java, sql, spring, kotlin

Im new to SQL relations, Im using spring, and im wanting to make a OneToMany relationship between a customer and a ticket, eg Customer can have multiple tickets but ticket cant have multiple customers, heres what ive got,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tickets")
data class Ticket(
    @Id
    val id:Long,
    val ticketId:String,
    val price:Int,
    val openDate:LocalDateTime,
    val closeDate:LocalDateTime,
    @ManyToOne
    val customer:Customer
)


@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
data class Customer(
    @Id
    val id:Long,
    val email:String,
    val discordUserId:String,
    val amountSpent:Int,
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id", table = "tickets")
    val tickets:Set<Ticket>
)
```

However, I get an error on startup

> Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Collections having FK in secondary table

Just wondering how I can resolve this,

Comment: Is Rekatuibshuo something related to your stack/framework?

Comment: I dont know what Rekauibshuo is sorry

Comment: And why did you add it to your title?

Comment: Oh damn, thats a major typo haha its meant to be 'relationship' lmao, can i edit it?

Comment: You can edit in Stackoverflow, it's encouraged even for fixing typo and adding information (without changing the intention and invalidating answer)

Comment: alright, doing rn, any idea regarding the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement bidirectional relationship between your classes like [this](https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-data/kotlin-springjpa-hibernate-one-many-relationship):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
data class Customer(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id:Long,
    var email:String,
    var discordUserId:String,
    var amountSpent:Int,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var tickets:Set<Ticket> = setOf()
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "tickets")
data class Ticket(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id:Long,
    var ticketId:String,
    var price:Int,
    var openDate:LocalDateTime,
    var closeDate:LocalDateTime,
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", nullable=false)
    var customer: Customer? = null
)
```